# Spring:define bean's property(ref to other bean) as optional

Tags: spring, reference, properties, javabeans, autowired

Have two bean definitions:

file a.xml

```
<bean id="A" class="com.A">
 <property name="bClass" ref="B"/>
</bean>
```

file b.xml

```
<bean id="B" class="com.B"/>
```

In some cases file b.xml does not contain definition of bean B.
And from other side,file a.xml always contains link to B definition.

How to define reference to B bean to be **optional**, in order to avoid `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Autowired(required=false) helped

Comment: how come? You don't use `@autowired` in your setup. How does the annotation apply then?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If you have a reference to `B`, then `B` must exist.  You need to ensure that some kind of stub `B` exists, the definition of which would be overridden by the definition of `B` in `b.xml`.

Alternatively, don't inject `B` into `A`, but make `A` look up `B` using `BeanFactory.getBean("B")`, and handle the potential absence of `B` programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility (on top of these suggested by skaffman) is to reverse the depenency. Let the bean `B` know the bean `A`. It can even register itself within it - that is, call the setter, e.g.:

```
public class B {
  private A a;

  public void init() {
    a.setB(this);
  }
}
```